# What is the best way to restrict any routes in Laravel 5.0?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5, php-5.5

I want to restrict some routes of my application and only allow that to only my authenticated user.

I tried check using the `auth:check()` function but it doesn't seem to work.

```
// Route Restriction
if (Auth::check()){

    //Web Directory
    Route::get('web-directory','WebDirectoryController@index');
}
```

---

When I got to `mysite/web-directory` I still get 404 Error - even if I'm currently log-in.

[image]

What is the best way to restrict any routes in Laravel 5.0 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All right, so I figured out the solution to my own question.

I restrict my routes by doing this

```
// Route group
$router->group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {

    //Web Directory
    Route::get('web-directory','WebDirectoryController@index');
}
```

Now, I can go to my route fine, and 404 Error will only kick in when the user is not yet log-in.

I hope this help someone.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved by restricting routes individually too:

```
Route::get('web-directory', [
    'middleware' => 'auth', 
    'uses' => 'WebDirectoryController@index'
]);
```